# Spock Framework how to test spring boot application context

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spock, applicationcontext

I use Spock Framework with Groovy scripts to test my Java application. I have 100% Test coverage in my project for all the classes that I created. However, I notice that the coverage shows that the main class called "App" is not fully tested.

Here is my App class to boot Spring application:

```
 package com.test.cli;

 import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
 import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
 import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

 @SpringBootApplication
 public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);

    App app = context.getBean(App.class);
    app.start();
  }

  private void start() {
    System.out.print("App started ...");
  }

 }
```

And this is the single test that I have for App class:

```
 package com.test.cli

 import com.test.cli.App
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
 import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
 import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
 import spock.lang.Specification


 @SpringBootTest(classes = App.class)
 class AppSpecIT extends Specification {

  @Autowired
  ApplicationContext context

  def "it should boot Spring application successfully"() {
    expect: "application context exists"
    context != null
  }

 }
```

You can see in this screenshot, line from 12 to 18 are not covered and I would like to fix that:[image: App Test coverage result]

How to fully test Spring Boot application context with Spock Framework?

Comment: Can you please tell how you resolve this issue..?? Facing the same issue. I am new to Spock and spring so not able to understand Leonard's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@SpringBootTest` only instantiates the class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` or any other configuration classes explicitly configured via `classes`. However the static `main` method is not executed, and should only contain the glue code `SpringApplication.run(App.class, args)` anyway. If you'd want to test it then you'll have to explicitly call it, but I'd advise against it you can read about why here [The tragedy of 100% code coverage](https://labs.ig.com/code-coverage-100-percent-tragedy).

If you need something like the start method to be called after start use a `org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner` or `org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner` instead.